# Youtube data API in XML

Tags: xml, json, api, youtube, qjson

I'm working with the data api. I want to retrieve data from a specific video.
That works with JSON in PHP. But I need to do that in Qt, that's why XML is easier because I have done it before and its implented in Qt itself. QJson, on the other hand, is a third party "plugin".

So I wonder if there is a way that I can get the data in XML instead of JSON?

If not I was thinking of converting the JSON to XML in PHP, then request that link in Qt.

([the json data](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xyF6s6F2tbg?v=2&alt=json) I want to retrieve in XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove alt=json from query string

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/xyF6s6F2tbg?v=2

Comment: cannot believe that I didn't think of that. I replaced the json with xml never tought to just remove it. Thank you!